# I keep getting Invalid Token error in python cryptography (cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken)

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, fernet

I wrote this prototype code to encrypt some text (and vice - versa). I keep getting this error when I set the command to `self.get()` while `self.write` works as it should. I have no idea what causes this error or how to solve it...Help...

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class EncodingText:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = Fernet.generate_key()
        self.f = Fernet(self.key)
        self.get()

    def write(self):
        stuff = "hello there".encode()
        token = self.f.encrypt(stuff)
        open_file_for_edit = open("file.txt", 'wb')
        open_file_for_edit.write(token)
        open_file_for_edit.close()

    def get(self):
        read_file = open("file.txt", 'rb')
        reading = read_file.read()
        print(reading)
        token = self.f.decrypt(reading)
        print(token)
        read_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EncodingText()
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 113, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 70, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line 78, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/xoxo/Desktop/Python Programs/xoxo/xoxo.py", line 26, in <module>
    EncodingText()
  File "c:/Users/xoxo/Desktop/Python Programs/xoxo/xoxo.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.get()
  File "c:/Users/xoxo/Desktop/Python Programs/xoxo/xoxo.py", line 20, in get
    tokenf = self.f.decrypt(reading)
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 76, in 
decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl, int(time.time()))
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 125, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "C:\Users\xoxo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 115, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Comment: Assuming `write` method was not called, the code is bound to fail.

Comment: Another possible cause would be: Each instantiation of `EncodingText` creates a _new_ key. So if you encrypt with one instance (with `self.write()` in the constructor) and decrypt with another using the above code, it should also fail because of different keys.

Comment: @Topaco That is the other (potential) reason. I'll demonstrate it as a complete answer.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us go through the code line by line:

1. In the method `__init__`:

   1. Line 1: key generation.

      ```py
      self.key = Fernet.generate_key()  # this is called
      ```

      We are generating a **random key** every time the method is called.
   2. Line 2: Cipher generation

      ```py
      self.f = Fernet(self.key)
      ```

      We are creating a cipher with a **completely random key**.
   3. Line 3: Decryption

      ```py
      self.get()
      ```

      We are calling a new method.
2. In method `get`:

   1. Line 1, 2 and 3: Reading a file

      ```py
      read_file = open("file.txt", 'rb')
      reading = read_file.read()
      print(reading)
      ```

      Here, 2 things are possible.

      1. The file is missing from the path, and `FileNotFoundError` is raised and the program halts.
      2. The file is present.

      Assuming, the file is present (#2). The file contents will be read and the contents will be printed.
   2. Line 4: Decryption

      ```py
      token = self.f.decrypt(reading)
      ```

      Here, our file contents will be decrypted. Remember that, from point 1.1.1 and
      1.1.2, each time our program is called, a random key is generated and the cipher
      is generated with a random key.

      Since `Fernet`, by implementation, uses `AES`, which is a symmetric cipher, we require the same key
      for encryption and decryption.

      But, by 1.1.1 and 1.1.2, we are generating a random key each time the program
      runs.

      This explains the error message. The cipher is trying to decrypt the data from
      the file which was encrypted with a completely random key with another random
      key, which leads to incorrect decryption.

---

If you insert `self.write()` before `self.get()`, the program runs. This is because
the same key is used to decrypt the data.